# Rails Devise Errors—how to change case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have this flash message coming up:

```
Invalid Email or password
```

I really want to downcase the "Email" so it becomes:

```
Invalid email or password
```

---

In `devise.en.yml` I see this line:

```
invalid: "Invalid %{authentication_keys} or password."
```

I tried doing:

```
invalid: "Invalid %{authentication_keys.downcase} or password."
```

But that made the view show:

```
Invalid %{authentication_keys.downcase} or password.
```

Comment: If you are authenticating by `email`, can't you just use `Invalid email or password` in the yml file?

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/4538

Comment: @Subash I could just change it to `email`, but the point is how can I modify `yml` files?

Comment: @Mirror318 calling functions like downcase in yml files is not allowed. Or you like to implement a custom inflector for translations, but I think you don't want ! You can try to find the line, where devise takes the "authentication_keys" from and then change that label Email to email. 
If you, like @Subash mentioned, only have authentication with email you can change the translation in the file to `invalid: "Invalid email or password."`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @SimonFranzen, you should submit this as an answer

Comment: @Mirror318 done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to find the line, where devise takes the "authentication_keys" from and then change that label Email to email.

OR

If you, like @Subash mentioned, only have authentication with email you can change the translation in devise.en.yml to

`invalid: "Invalid email or password."`